# Removing XML elements using LINQ

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have the code written to add the entries, edit the different elements etc., but I am having a hard time find the best way to remove an entry in my XML file. This is not for a lack of researching. Ideally, I would like to pass a user name into the procedure and query the XML file for the username and then remove userPc, userName and sign in date. The plan is to run the procedure on form closing. Can you please help me write the method for this?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
  <user>
    <userPC>assetTagNumber</userPC>
    <userName>userName</userName>
    <signInDate>01/01/2014 01:00:00</signInDate>
  </user>
  <user>
    <userPC>assetTagNumber2</userPC>
    <userName>userName2</userName>
    <signInDate>01/01/2014 01:00:01</signInDate>
  </user>
</user>
```

Here is my current `loginClass` :

```
Public Class loginClass

    Dim xmlCheckInFilePath As String = "\\itfs1\help_share$\ITCSToolBoxAdmin\AppAdmin\User_CheckIn\user.xml"
    Dim asset As String = Environment.MachineName
    Dim user As String = Environment.UserName
    Dim signInDate As String = DateTime.Now

    Public Sub loginToXmlFile()
        Try
            runDupeCheckQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to run DupeCheckQuery in login class.", "loginClass", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub runDupeCheckQuery()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlCheckInFilePath)
        Dim appQuery = _
            From c In doc.<user>.<user> _
            Select c.<userName>
        For Each result In appQuery
            If result.Value = user Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        addEntry()
    End Sub

    Private Sub addEntry()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlCheckInFilePath)
        Dim newEntry As XElement = _
        <user>
            <userPC><%= asset %></userPC>
            <userName><%= user %></userName>
            <signInDate><%= signInDate %></signInDate>
        </user>
        doc.Root.Add(newEntry)
        doc.Save(xmlCheckInFilePath)
    End Sub

    Public Sub removeEntry()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: We can **help** you write the method, but you have to show what you've been able to write on your own first.

Comment: sure. I will add the login class.

Comment: I have added the login class. I feel comfortable with working with LINQ&XML EXCEPT for the removing. I definitely don't want someone to just write code for me, I need to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`XNode.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which removes the node from it's current parent.

I haven't tested the code, but should at least give you an idea how to approach the problem.

```
Public Sub removeEntry()

    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlCheckInFilePath)

    Dim userEntry As XElement = doc.<user>.<user>.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.<userName>.Value = user)

    If userEntry IsNot Nothing Then userEntry.Remove()

    doc.Save(xmlCheckInFilePath)

End Sub
```

Comment: How does this code know to delete the other two elements associated with userName ? Won't this just remove the userName element and leave the userPC  ?

Comment: I see I could run the query to return the other details, ie userPC and signInDate and then do the .Remove() function on them all. Seems like extra steps.

Comment: It will delete `<user>` element, not `<userName>`. And because all other elements are children of that one, they will be removed automatically.